# Como buscar múltiplos dados no mysql sem perder desempenho

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Tenho uma tabela chamada "readings" onde minha busca retorna 10 mil resultados referentes ao equipamentid = 1

```
SELECT id, result, date FROM readings WHERE equipamentid  = 1;
```

para cada resultado retornado eu preciso trazer outro dado com data menor igual mais próxima referente agora ao equipamentid = 2

```
SELECT result FROM readings WHERE equipamentid = 2 AND date <= date(data da primeira busca) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

O código funciona perfeitamente, porém como a primeira busca retorna 10 mil resultados, é realizado outras 10 mil buscas do próximo equipamento, o que torna tudo muito lento.
Já tentei também realizar usando o LEFT JOIN mas o tempo de execução é o mesmo, fica inviável.

Existe outra maneira que não consegui ainda visualizar para resolver este problema, e ganhar desempenho?

Comment: já criou índice para otimizar a consulta? [link](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3620/indices-mysql-otimizacao-de-consultas.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que eu entendi da sua pergunta, é que a cada resultado do primeiro `SELECT` você faz uma nova consulta pegando sempre um único registro com uma data menor ou igual a cada registro retornado pelo primeiro `SELECT`. Certo?

Ou seja, serão 10 mil consultas diferentes.

**E é ai que está o erro!**

Pois se você precisa pegar todos os registros com a data igual ou menor que a data do equipamento com `equipamentid  = 1` basta pegar a MAIOR data deste registro e filtrar no segundo `SELECT`, assim ele irá trazer todos os registros de uma vez.

Este `SELECT` mantém:

```
SELECT id, result, date FROM readings WHERE equipamentid  = 1;
```

Pois você precisa desses resultados.

O segundo, você altera para isso:

```
SELECT result
FROM readings
WHERE equipamentid = 2 
AND data <= 
(
  SELECT data FROM readings WHERE equipamentid = 1 ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Assim, você terá o resultados com `result` onde `equipamentid = 2`

Comment: Opa André, quase isso, vamos lá...

Imagine que as 3 primeiras linhas do equipamentid = 1 são:

#1 date(03/03/2020 10:10:00); result(10)
#2 date(02/03/2020 10:10:00); result(9)
#3 date(01/03/2020 10:10:00); result(8)

para a 1º linha da consulta acima, eu agora preciso trazer um result do equipamentid = 2, menor ou igual a data da 1º linha mais próximo, ou seja o primeiro a ser encontrado em ordem decrescente.

Comment: Eu preciso, além do result do equipamentid = 2, o result do equipamentid = 1 e a data do equipamentid = 1

Comment: @GustavoPaes mas então, você faz a primeira consulta normal com `equipamentid  = 1` DEPOIS você faz a segunda consulta que eu publiquei e lá estarão todos os valores que você precisa. Entendeu?

Comment: @GustavoPaes fiz uma edição para deixar mais claro

Comment: Andrei, na sua query ele traz apenas o result do equipament 2, eu preciso de um result do 2 para cada linha do result do 1, e ainda a coluna date do 1, na sua query ele traz apenas os dados do equipamento 2

Comment: Da forma como está, a segunda query que vc colocou trás todos os os registros do equipament 2, eu preciso do result 2 com data igual menor mais próximo da data do equipament 1, se eu não trouxer os dados prontos na query depois eu vou ter que comparar diretamente no php. pois enquanto o euqipament 1 pode ter 10 mil registros o equipament 2 pode ter 20 milregistro no mesmo periodo de tempo...

Comment: Para facilitar,  criei uma tabela para você entender o resultado que preciso, acredito que não estou sabendo te explicar, da uma olhada nas colunas com comentários https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m8xat-R9I02BA_Cn_HcsvaEJPGKoFEN3

Comment: @GustavoPaes ok, mais tarde vou dar uma analisada

Answer (score 1):

Para melhorar a performance sugiro o seguinte:

1. Indexa os campos utilizados na clausura WHERE
2. É preferível pegar tudo utilizando junção ou subconsulta e tratar programaticamente,pois da forma que você esta fazendo prejudica muito a aplicação:

> O código funciona perfeitamente, porém como a primeira busca retorna
>   10 mil resultados, é realizado outras 10 mil buscas

Abrir 10.001 conexões mesmo que só para consulta consome muito mais recurso do que 1 unica consulta.

**Resumindo tente assim:**

```
SELECT 
  p.id,
  p.result,
  p.date,
  (SELECT s.result FROM readings s WHERE s.equipamentid = 2 AND s.date <= p.date ORDER BY s.date DESC LIMIT 1) as result2
FROM readings p
WHERE equipamentid = 1
```